# Serialize python dict to json with string without quotes

Tags: python, json, serialization

I want to serialize a python object to JSON, however for one special type of object, I would like to have a string serialized without quotes (the reason being that in the application it will not refer to a string, but to a function). I.e. the end result is supposed to look like this

```
{"field": "age", "key": myfunc}
```

where here `myfunc` is a function. Is there a way from python to do this directly - without using `.replace` on the serialized string, but instead passing a special object?

Thanks

Comment: That is not valid JSON, so no, the Python `json` encoder will never produce this (that is a *feature* of the encoder, that it only produces valid JSON). What you are asking for doesn't make sense, what you are asking for isn't JSON, but now, your own format.

Comment: [Here is a link to the JSON standard, btw](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf)

Comment: Motivation is to use this when creating e.g. settings for inclusion in programmatically created javascript. But ok, I guess I need a clumsy workaround ... thanks for your comment though.